# Stuck at fsck "/dev/sda1: clean xxx/xxx files [...] " after upgrade to Ubuntu 16 from 14

Tags: boot, nvidia, upgrade, xorg, fsck

I've updated my Ubuntu distro, and since then everytime I boot the system I am stuck at the fsck screen

> /dev/sda1: clean xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks

I`ve already trying accessing tty and installing xorg and/or nvidia drivers but keep getting the same error message from sudo apt-get install:

> apt-get: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0: symbol....

I had a GPU installed in my system at the time of the distro upgrade, but I've also tried a multitude of "fixes" with the GPU deactivated by the BOOT settings and none seem to work neither.

Can anyone help me with that?
Thanks

Edit 1:
Following the demand on a comment, I loged into recovery root and:

```
# sudo blkid 
/dev/sdb: PTUUID="000d2ed6" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/sata1: UUID="6ad5e12f-8d6f-4659-b5d4-8fe9eb9d11df" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c537cdcf-01"

# cat /etc/fstab/
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
# 
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a 
# device; this may be used with a UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <options>     <dump>   <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=6ad5e12f-8d6f-4659-b5d4-8fe9eb9d11df /     ext4    errors=remount-ro  0     1

# free -h
           total     used    free    shared    buff/cache    availabe
Mem:        7.7G      37M    7.5G      8.2M          162M        7.4G
Swap:         0B       0B      0B

# swap on
# _ (no output here)
```

Comment: If you can get to recovery mode from the GRUB menu, and go to root access, show me these commands... `sudo blkid`, `cat /etc/fstab`, `free -h`, and `swapon`. Edit that info into your question please. Start comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema edited the question with the data you asked for. Than you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It all looks good, except that you've got no swap partition or /swapfile. That's not causing your current problem, but it's something that needs fixing. Please see my partial answer and we'll check your file system first. What is on sdb? Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I had some USB connections to a development board I was working on, I believe sdb is one of those.

Comment: Does it boot if you disconnect sdb? Let me know about the fsck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to fix my problem.
It looks like it was caused by issues from PPA for Ubuntu toolchain. 
I downloaded (from tty terminal) the debian of package libstdc++6 for Xenial at http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libstdc++6

In my case (amd64) I did the following (on tty, <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> on the "error" screen):

```
# wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb
# dpkg -i libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4_amd64.deb
# reboot
```

And voilà, that solved the problem :)

Comment: How did you figure that out? You should still create a swap partition or a /swapfile. You can accept your own answer to close the question.

Comment: As @heynnema mentioned, how did you realize `libstdc++6` is the cause of the issue?

Comment: I figured out that apt-get was not working, then I looked out for a fix (so that I could reinstall the video drivers), and ended out finding a forum post where someone mentioned that his computer was not booting because of the same problems I had on apt-get. Then I fixed it and everything is working fine again.

Answer (score 2):

You'll also run into this exact error if you run out of disk space as well. I was stuck at boot

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> into `tty2` login

`df -h` says `/dev/sda1` is `100%` used

I find the stuff I need to delete with this command

```
du -d1 -h /home/username | sort -h
```

For example, I deleted some folders like so

```
sudo rm -rf /home/username/Desktop/folder/*
sudo rm -rf /home/username/.cache/*
sudo rm -rf /home/username/.mozilla/*
```

`reboot` and now it boots up no problem now

Comment: I've spend ~1h trying to fix stack fsck until I've found this answer. This is soo stupid.. Why just not say that the space is missing

Answer (score 1):

**If you recently installed nvidia drivers**, you might have disabled nouveau drivers. In my case I managed to fix this by removing every occurrence of `nomodeset` from `/etc/default/grub` file and then by executing `sudo update-grub`.

This was because `nomodeset` disables the use of any graphic driver. I disabled my `nouveau` drivers before installing nvidia ones.

**Though this might not be the case with everyone.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the following commands to install Intel graphics card drivers:

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
apt update
apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

After that, run the below command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Then: `reboot`

From:
[How to install the newest xserver-xorg-video-intel on 18.04 Bionic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145718/how-to-instal-the-newest-xserver-xorg-video-intel-on-18-04-bionic)

Comment: I have been stuck at the stupid clean block screen for an hour now. Holy crap. I could buy you dinner, I GOT A DESKTOP!! WOOHOO!!! The problem was that all the answers are for Nvidia, this is the only one that supports intel integrated chips.