# Stuck at /dev/sda1: clean xxx/xxx files XUBUNTU 17.10

Tags: grub2, xubuntu, ubuntu-drivers, additional-drivers

I went through this [Stuck at fsck "/dev/sda1: clean xxx/xxx files [...] " after upgrade to Ubuntu 16 from 14](https://askubuntu.com/questions/923899/stuck-at-fsck-dev-sda1-clean-xxx-xxx-files-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16?answertab=active#tab-top) link and went to try the solution but on the "error" screen i.e { /dev/sda1: clean xxx/xxx files} the notebook hangs and i can't enter Ctrl + Alt + F1 to add the commands.

Hence, i'm still struggling to find to solve this issue.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Ctrl + Alt + F2 to  Ctrl + Alt + F7 ?
Ctrl + Alt + F1 doesn't work for me, but Ctrl + Alt + F2 worked for me.

The message is not an error code, but a message indicating file system checking **fsck** have checked your file system