# ubuntu 20.04 boot stuck on boot /dev/nvme0n1p8: clean , ...files, ... blocks

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, boot-repair

I am using ubuntu 20.04 with dual boot. And I am very new to the ubuntu.  But suddenly my ubuntu stuck on a black page and it says: /dev/nvme0n1p8: clean , ...files, ... blocks.

I try purge nvidia but it did not help. Does anyone knows why that could happen?  My windows works fine. But when I want to enter the ubuntu I cannot do it? It is just stucked there. I have many important documents codes and settings in ubuntu. So I want to make sure that the system is not failed. If anyone helps me solving this problem I will be really happy.
[image]

Comment: Is that your problem ? https://askubuntu.com/q/923899/1051814

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)